# Android studio: Project refresh failed.. error in opening zip file

Tags: android, gradle

I've installed Android Studio on my laptop and also run the updates from 0.52 to 0.61

After creating a new project or opening a sample project that I've downloaded it displays this error:

```
Gradle '{ProjectName}' project refresh failed
Error:Cause: error in opening zip file
```

I couldn't find anything related to this specific error on Google or anywhere else on Stackoverflow.

Please help?

Comment: Run it in `debug`mode, maybe You'll gather a detailed message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; how do I do that exactly? I tried clicking on "Attach debugger to Android process" and an empty window opened, so I guess it must be somewhere else?

Comment: Run it with `-d` parameter specified.

Comment: Please can you elaborate? Where do I go to do that?

Comment: As far as I know what Android Studio does under the hood is running gradle tasks. Find in configuration a place where You can add invocation parameters (run options?) and specify `-d` there.

Answer (score 3):

download manually

http://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip

and paste: (not unzipping)

C:\Users\ (USER NAME) \ .gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.12-all[hash code]/

> C:\Users\ (USER NAME) \ .gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.12-all[hash code]/gradle-1.12-all.zip

### update

For Mac OS X and Other Unix based OS, the path is

> ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.x/[hash code]/

Comment: I have downloaded it before. I don't have a folder 'gradle-1.12-all', only 'gradle-1.10-all' and 'gradle-1.10-bin'. Any ideas?

Comment: I discovered there's an update to version 0.8.1; I currently have version 0.6.1. Going to download the new version (which will take forever on my super slow connection) and see what happens.

Comment: you just have to download the version that tells you the name of the folder and then paste it there without uncompress. 
Now I am using this version `(1.12-all)` which I guess is the last

Comment: my version of android studio is `android-studio-bundle-135.1245622-windows`

Comment: what is the path for mac?

Comment: sorry, I guess it must be the same folder

Comment: @VasilySochinsky For Mac OS X and Other Unix based OS, the path is `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.x/[hash code]/`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after updating Android Studio from 2.2.3 to 2.3; Here is the solution that worked for me:

1) In your project open 'gradle-wrapper.properties', change the 'distributionUrl' value

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

2) In you project open the project's 'build.gradle' file, and change the classpath

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
```

This is the latest gradle setting.

Hope this work.

**NOTE**: The version of the gradle depends on your android studio version. So change the version(as in he code) according to that.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by...

- Going to Settings... > Gradle
- Selecting "Use local Gradle distribution."
- Pointed it to my Gradle zip file: **home/kersting/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.12-all/6vpvhqu0efs1fqmqr2decq1v12/gradle-1.12**

It should be something similar for you if you downloaded Gradle which you should have when you downloaded Android Studio. Be careful, the .gradle file may be hidden. I found it through the terminal, but "ls" didn't reveal it.